# Data-mining Facebook Profile and Returning Data In Terminal

Tags: python, facebook, access-token, data-mining

I am slightly new to python coding and I have a project coming up to which I've decided to make some code that when entering a Facebook users URL it will return all data that their profile has to offer. Any help would be greatly appreciated or if you have code that does similar I would love to observe.

I am looking for this to be executed in python.

Comment: Scraping their frontend pages is against Facebook's terms, and they have measures in place against it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a web scraping framework with python. There are tons of them. Beautiful Soup, Scrapy are great options. However, most web applications do have security in place to prevent you from scraping data on their platforms. I would recommend you do more research.